# W3 Total Cache Wordpress plugin disturbing my page layout

Tags: php, wordpress, caching, plugins, pagespeed

I am using **W3 Total Cache** plugin to improve speed of my website. I am following [this article](http://www.wpexplorer.com/wordpress-w3-total-cache/) to set it up, under **Minify** tab when I set it to auto it disturbs my page structure and I guess disables my CSS.

Here is a screenshot. Under general settings tab when I set minify mode to auto it disturbs my theme.

[image: Screenshot]

Here is my disturbed theme:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try to uninstall W3 Total Cache plugin

and

tr to install the cache plugin, WP Super Cache

Answer (score 0):

If you set to manual minifying, you need to load all your scripts and css files manually. You can do so with the help of the wizard, the help button on top of the minify tab. You can load everything there and then purge setting and see what happens.

If it still breaks down your site, you need to change the order of the files. There is a load order dependency, so you will need to figure it out.

Hope it helps.